# Given: $ \frac{xm_2 + yn_2}{xm_1 + yn_1} < k $ etc., show: $ \frac{xm_2^g + yn_2^g}{xm_1^g+yn_1^g} < k. $

Tags: inequality, ratio

**Given**: Strictly positive numbers, $$ m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2, x, y, g, k $$ which satisfy the following properties:
$$ m_1 + m_2 = n_1 + n_2 $$
$$ \frac{m_2}{m_1} \le k \le \frac{n_2}{n_1} \le 1 $$
$$ \frac{m_2}{n_2} \le 1 \le \frac{m_1}{n_1} $$
$$ 1 \le g $$
$$ \frac{xm_2 + yn_2}{xm_1 + yn_1} < k < 1. $$

**Show**: For all feasible values, we have $$ \frac{xm_2^g + yn_2^g}{xm_1^g+yn_1^g} < k. $$

Comment: You can show that $(xm_2^g+yn_2^g)/(xm_1^g+yn_1^g)$ is a decreasing function of $g>1$. Use differentiation.

Comment: That works, thanks! It is in fact a decreasing function of _g_ > 0.